# Rendering PDF inside email body

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, pdf

I have generated PDF reports that I am sending as an attachment and what I want to do next is to render them within the body of the email. I have been going bonkers over this one but could not find a way to render it. 
What I have so far is:

```
//PDF Generation
MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
StringBuilder status = new StringBuilder("");
DateTime dTime = DateTime.Now;

Document doc = new Document();
doc.SetMargins(0 f, 0 f, 0 f, 0 f);

//Create PDF Table with 7 columns  
PdfPTable tableLayout2 = new PdfPTable(7);
doc.SetMargins(0 f, 0 f, 0 f, 50 f);

// .. some code 
//PDF Generation


PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, workStream).CloseStream = false;
// some more code  here
byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
workStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
workStream.Position = 0;

//INSTEAD OF AN ATTACHMENT HERE
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(workStream, "DailyReport:" + x.FirstName + x.LastName + ".pdf"));
using(SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient {
  EnableSsl = true,
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxxxx@xxxx.com", "xxxxxx")
}) {
  client.Send(message);
}
```

Instead of an attachment like this:

```
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(workStream, "DailyReport:" + x.FirstName + x.LastName + ".pdf"));
```

I want it to be inlined within the email body.

Comment: not all email clients can do that.

Comment: What's my best shot then?

Comment: make it a regular attachment?

Comment: regular attachment as in?

Comment: As in a normal attachment to an email.

Comment: You show the code in your question that makes it an attachment...

Comment: Pardon me. but I am already sending it as an attachment (runtime). and I do not want to neither as a regular attachment. Is there any way to render it in the body? Like we normally get a pdf in our mails from Ad companies. something like that?

Comment: "we normally get a pdf in our mails from Ad companies". Do you? Are you sure it's not HTML, or perhaps it's been converted into an image first? Anyway, as Daniel noted originally, if this is indeed possible, then not all email clients support it, so it's risky because the recipient might not be able to read it. But all the material online I can find suggests that what actually happens is that the PDF (or part of it) gets converted to an image in order to make it show within the email body.

Comment: Or it could be that when you receive the mentioned ad emails, your email software is actually just opening an Adobe Acrobat window embedded within the email body to allow the PDF (which is really just an attachment) to be displayed. Note this is a feature of the receiving client to enhance user-friendliness, but in this scenario there is no change to the way the PDF was originally added to the email - it's still just an attachment.

Comment: You generate the PDF file and then some HTML to include on the email body.

Comment: @ADyson how do you suggest I convert the above `workStream` into a base64 image that is rendered on the email body (without saving the image locally as everything is being runtime generated)

Comment: Just the normal way using Convert.ToBase64String() - it accepts an array of bytes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx